# libuv - how to keep default loop run until at least one thread in program is alive?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, libuv

`server` will start in new thread after `start` is called (server has own loop).
Problem is that the program ends immediately, because there is no event registred on default loop. What i want is to simulate `pthread_join` through the `uv_default_loop`.
I want avoid calling some custom `join` method on all objects, which should run in separated thread, to keep the main thread alive.

**important part of main function:**

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    ...
    TcpServer server("127.0.0.1", 7777);   
    server.start();
    uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
    uv_loop_close(uv_default_loop());
    return 0;
}
```

**main function:**

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    /* initialize openssl random generator */
    const char * seed = "asfanfasfflalkhflhafoih";
    RAND_seed(seed, (size_t)strlen(seed));

    uv_tty_t tty;
    uv_tty_init(uv_default_loop(), &tty, 0, 1);
    uv_tty_set_mode(&tty, 0);
    uv_read_start((uv_stream_t *)&tty, allocateBuffer_cb, tty_read_cb);

    // unref tty, it shouldn't keep the loop alive
    uv_unref((uv_handle_t *)&tty);

    uv_signal_t sigterm;
    uv_signal_init(uv_default_loop(), &sigterm);
    uv_signal_start(&sigterm, signal_handler, SIGTERM);

    uv_signal_t sigint;
    uv_signal_init(uv_default_loop(), &sigint);
    uv_signal_start(&sigint, signal_handler, SIGINT);

    // unref signal handlers, they shoudn't keep the loop alive
    uv_unref((uv_handle_t * )&sigterm);
    uv_unref((uv_handle_t * )&sigint);

    TcpServer server("127.0.0.1", 7777, uv_default_loop());

    server.start();

    uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

    uv_loop_close(uv_default_loop());

    // we should reset tty before end
    uv_tty_reset_mode();

    return 0;
}
```

**SOLVED:** i found this topic, which is really good 

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/Sob97-QbtlA
The solution is that each new thread should register `uv_async_t` in `uv_default_loop()`, so loop will be still alive if there is at least one active thread. When the thread should quit, it can probably just `uv_close` that `uv_async_t`, registred in main loop.

Answer (score -3):

I did not test, but can we try this way?

Put `uv_run` into a infinite loop like this.

```
while(someflag)
{
    uv_run( uv_default_loop );
}
```

And put this loop into a thread. 
If there is no event registered in uv_loop, it will call `uv_run` until `someflag == false`. So you can use `uv_async_send` or other ways to end this loop asynchronously.